# python 2.7: how best to delete a variable referenced in dict comprehension?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, syntax-error

I have encountered what appears to be a limitation of manual garbage collection when using `dict` comprehensions.

```
def f():
  first_dict = {'a':4, 'b':2}
  second_dict = {k:first_dict[k] for k in ['a']}
  del first_dict
```

generates this when run in python 2.7:

```
SyntaxError: can not delete variable 'first_dict' referenced in nested scope
```

This doesn't happen with list comprehensions, and neither with python 3. To work around this, I could, for example, use a for loop (slow) or perhaps create a list of tuples and make my dict from that? Any better ideas?

***EDIT:*** Here's a couple of similar use cases where @JeffMercado's suggesting (in a comment) won't work:

```
import numpy as np
import gc
def f(stuff):
  # stuff is a dict of lists of array indices

  # get a numpy array, perhaps from a db or via some convluted calculation. I'm using np.arange as a dummy
  arr = np.arange(10)

  # a problematic 'nested scope' indexing into arr
  ret_1 = {k:arr[indices] for k,indices in stuff}

  # another problematic 'nested scope' invoking a function
  ret_2 = {k:cool_function(arr,v) for k,v in stuff}

  # do some more calculations to generate other return values
  other_ret = 'other return values'

  # cleanup intermediary data to release memory for other processes
  del arr
  gc.collect(0)

  return ret_1, ret_2, other_ret
```

Ok, so you could probably do something ugly like `{k:v for k,indicies in stuff for i,v in enumerate(arr) if i in indices}`to work around `ret_1`, but `ret_2` is not so easily fixed.

Comment: This works but I don't know the rules enough to explain why this works over your original approach: `{k:v for k,v in first_dict.iteritems() if k in ['a']}`

Comment: it works because the values do not directly refer to first_dict. My actual use cases are a bit more complex, and selecting elements of first_dict won't work - I'll change the question a bit to reflect that. Apologies..

Comment: scratch that! I just tried `{k:v for k,indicies in stuff for v in arr}`, which doesn't make much sense, but DOES generate the syntax error! I have to admit the logic of it is beyond me.

Comment: substituting `first_dict = None` for `del first_dict` works (at least it doesn't generate a syntax error).

Comment: @tdelaney I do believe you're right.. I like it: no ugly workarounds and the memory can be freed (: Want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a list of tuples that seems to work:

```
def f():
    first_dict = {'a':4, 'b':2}
    second_dict = dict([(k,first_dict[k]) for k in ['a']])
    del first_dict
```

This isn't ideal, as it has to create the list (which is probably large, hence the desire to delete it). Unfortunately, if I use a generator thus:

```
def f():
    first_dict = {'a':4, 'b':2}
    second_dict = dict((k,first_dict[k]) for k in ['a'])
    del first_dict
```

I still get the syntax error ):